# Python: Creating a function counting specific words in a textfile

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, word-count

I want to create  a function that returns the value of word count of a specific word in a text file.

Here's what I currently have:

```
def Word_Counter(Text_File, Word):

    Data = open(Text_File, 'r').read().lower()

    count = Data.count(Word)


    print(Word, "; ", count)

Word_Counter('Example.txt', "the")
```

Which returns: "the ;  35"

That is pretty much what I want it to do. But what if I want to test a text for a range of words. I want the words (key) and values in say a list or dictionary. What's a way of doing that without using modules?

Say if I tested the function with this list of words: [time, when, left, I, do, an, who, what, sometimes].

The results I would like would be something like:

`Word Counts = {'time': 1, 'when': 4, 'left': 0, 'I': 5, 'do': 2, 'an': 0, 'who': 1, 'what': 3, 'sometimes': 1}`

I have been able to create a dictionary which does a word count for every word, like example below.

```
wordfreq = {}
for word in words.replace(',', ' ').split():
   wordfreq[word] = wordfreq.setdefault(word, 0) + 1
```

I'd like to do a similar style but only targeting specific words, any suggestions?

Comment: As an aside, you should probably have a read of PEP-8 regarding capitalisation of names. It makes it more confusing to read with functions and variables defined with capital letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your given code, I did not test this.

```
def Word_Counter(Text_File, word_list):

        Data = open(Text_File, 'r').read().lower()
        output = {}
        for word in word_list:
           output[word] = Data.count(Word)
```

Or you can do this

```
text = open("sample.txt", "r") 

# Create an empty dictionary 
d = dict() 

# Loop through each line of the file 
for line in text: 
    # Remove the leading spaces and newline character 
    line = line.strip() 

    # Convert the characters in line to  
    # lowercase to avoid case mismatch 
    line = line.lower() 

    # Split the line into words 
    words = line.split(" ") 

    # Iterate over each word in line 
    for word in words: 
        # Check if the word is already in dictionary 
        if word in d: 
            # Increment count of word by 1 
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else: 
            # Add the word to dictionary with count 1 
            d[word] = 1
```

Comment: Fair warning - This may break for large file.

Comment: that's great, and you're right. Larger text files it may struggle. But does what I need it to do! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

Try the following:

```
keywords = ['the', 'that']
worddict = {}

with open('out.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read().split(' ')  # or f.read().split(',')

for word in text:
    worddict[word] = worddict[word]+1 if word in worddict else 1

print([{x, worddict[x]} for x in keywords])
```

Comment: This seems to return the word count of every word in the text, rather than the key words?

Comment: @AllenPeck that's not a problem at all :) See the updated